# Fetch error message failed!DSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, Error Code = 17,001

Tags: oracle11g, websphere, datasource

I have a fresh server Wepshere 7.0.0.17 and created a couple of Data sources (Oracle database and Oracle client 11.2.0 and the databse server version is 10g). I am getting the below error while testing the data sources which I used to get before as well but would disappear after a fresh restart of the Websphere. However, this time around it simply doesn't go away despite several restarts including entire server restarts!
Any hints on what could be causing this issue?

```
[3/25/14 4:49:06:811 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R java.sql.SQLException: Internal Error: Fetch error message failed!DSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, Error Code = 17,001
[3/25/14 4:49:06:811 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.checkError(T2CConnection.java:757)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:811 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:414)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:811 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:811 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:162)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:811 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:53)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:811 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:812 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:812 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:812 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:139)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:812 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:88)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:812 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper$2.run(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1664)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:812 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4588)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:812 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4766)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:813 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:813 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper$3.run(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1680)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:813 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:813 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getPooledConnection(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1692)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:813 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getPooledConnection(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1587)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:813 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getConnectionFromDSOrPooledDS(DSConfigurationHelper.java:3219)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:813 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.testConnectionForGUI(DSConfigurationHelper.java:3895)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:814 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:814 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:814 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:814 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:814 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnectionToDataSource2(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:556)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:814 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnection(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:484)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:814 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:815 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:815 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:815 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:815 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:815 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:815 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:815 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:815 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:816 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:816 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:816 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:816 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:816 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:816 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1332)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:816 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:817 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1225)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:817 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:817 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:242)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:817 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:353)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:817 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:595)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:817 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:817 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:818 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:818 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:818 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:818 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:818 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[3/25/14 4:49:06:818 EDT] 00000019 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this by adding the oracle lib32 folder to startServer.sh file.